# Error when creating a window: cannot initiiate type shell

Tags: eclipse, swt

My issue with Eclipse is that I keep getting errors when I change anything, I've changed it to different things and I eventually gave up.

```java
package MainWindowPackage;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class SWTApplicationLoad {
    

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object Display;
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        Shell shell2 = new Shell();
        
        shell2.setSize(450, 300);
        shell2.setText("SWT Application");

        shell2.open();
        shell2.layout();
        while (!shell2.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        
    }

}
```

I keep getting errors everytime I make changes to this, what do I do? This is for Eclipse.

Comment: Is there more to that error message? A stack trace? Are you sure `display` came back not null--and why did you name a local Object "Display" as well?

Comment: Idk but I'm new, I found the correct way to run it but I forgot how.

Answer (score 0):

You should create the display with `new Display()` and dispose of it at the end. It is also normal to use the `Shell` constructor with the display argument and style:

```java
public static void main(final String[] args) {

  Display display = new Display();
  try {
      Shell shell2 = new Shell(display, SWT.SHELL_TRIM);

      shell2.setSize(450, 300);
      shell2.setText("SWT Application");

      shell2.open();
      shell2.layout();

      while (!shell2.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
           display.sleep();
        }
      }
  }
  finally {
    display.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: If this doesn't resolve the problem we need to see the full stack trace.